# Please settle or at least discuss this impression I have that command line answers are preferred here

Tags: discussion

I provide a lot of answers here and as much as possible I try to make my answers clear enough to be understood by a relatively new user. I realize that will probably annoy some highly experienced users, but lets face it, for Ubuntu to take hold we have to reach the least experienced users who are having difficulty.  I would think a highly experienced user would still be able to grok my explanations.

Time and time again it seems my answers are downvoted simply for not including lines intended to be copied and pasted directly into terminal.  Oh I understand that for a lot of people a single magical command is faster and easier than understanding my explanation, but lets face it, this is Ubuntu, not Minix.  We are using relatively slow highly graphical versions of Linux, so why downvote highly graphical solutions?

Depending how this goes, I'm pretty sure I'll pose similar questions regarding my general dissatisfaction with this site.

Comment: I don't have the feeling GUI answers are downvoted. On the contrary, I would upvote good solutions that offer *both* ways. There are however good reasons to provide *at least* a cli solution if possible, as pointed out (for example) here: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/12246/wouldnt-it-be-better-to-help-users-without-sending-them-to-the-terminal/12278#12278. It would make things clearer If you added some links where you have the feeling you were downvoted for the fact that you offered a non- cli solution.

Comment: I agree that it would probably make a better case, and indeed I would do exactly that were I not so tired.  I will try to come back to this and improve my question when I feel I have the mental resources.

Comment: There are always users that do not like GUI answers and ( often greenhorns) that do not vote shell solutions up :(

Comment: I checked your last 20 answers, there is actually only 1 down vote, which is not very often. It seems unlikely that that one is related to (not using) cli.

Answer (score 6):

I checked your latest 30 answers on downvotes. I found 1 downvote on [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/567949/72216) answer. Looking at the argumentation (assuming it is corresponding to the downvote), it has nothing to do with (not) using cli. 
"*Time and time again it seems my answers are downvoted simply for not including lines intended to be copied and pasted directly into terminal.*" - seems not the right qualification of the situation.

Apart from that, I don't have the feeling GUI answers are downvoted. On the contrary, I would upvote good solutions that offer both ways. There are however good reasons to provide *at least* a cli solution if possible, as pointed out (for example) [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/12246/wouldnt-it-be-better-to-help-users-without-sending-them-to-the-terminal/12278#12278).

Comment: Perhaps I should have explained where it is I'm coming from.  You see, I became so despondent about my perfectly valid answers being downvoted that I began deleting them while inserting micro-rants about distaste for being downvoted apparently for omitting CLI commands while trying to help users of a flavor of linux quite as graphical as Ubuntu is designed to be.  It was a little of both, certainly, but if you don't see the downvoted answers, that would probably be because I deleted them already, and I'm not happy about it.

Comment: I don't think deleting them and replacing them with rants is an effective way of improving the situation; a more effective way would be to add the questions to your post so that the rest of us can examine if there is a problem.